# Are these different types of classes the same?

Tags: class, oop

I know that a class can inherit from another class, but there are lots of different names for these.

- A `child class` inherits from a `parent class`
- A `subclass` inherits from a `superclass`
- A `derived class` inherits from a `base class`

Are these all just different names for the same thing? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: These seem like different names of the same thing.  I suppose in the right context it's *possible* that one of these may be used to attempt to refer to a class that's *defined* within another class, which isn't actually an inheritance structure.  But that sounds like an edge case here.  The terminology can be fairly interchangeable in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @David, I don't think I need to worry about classes defined within other classes for my specification so I guess I can treat them as the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally these **three** can be the same or different depending on the **context**,

A ***super*** class always suggest that it is the **root** class so does ***base*** class but ***parent*** class is a loose term. A parent class class can be a base class and derived class at the same time . It can be the superclass as well. So context matters .

I hope you get the idea .

Comment: So you're saying that a super/base class can't have a parent class? If its the **root** then it can't have any parents.

Comment: They are called super for a reason . That is it  :)